# Selecting date from current week monday to next Sunday

Tags: mysql, select

I have this query made out and I'm able to grab the dates from my table starting from the monday of the current week. My intentions are that the dates grabbed are from Monday to the upcoming Sunday. Below is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM spec_roaster
WHERE DATE(date)
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW())+ 7) % 7 DAY)
        AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW())+ 7) % 7 DAY)
ORDER BY date ASC
```

The returned results are:

[image]

I have tried to change the interval for the DATE_ADD but am always being returned to the Thursday of this week. Is there any way that I can change the interval so that it will return the dates until the next Sunday? I tried

```
INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(NOW()) - 4 + 7) % 7 DAY)
```

but that didn't have any changes, I also tried DATEDIFF but that gave me syntax errors. I'm hoping to hear some insights on how I could approach to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Following Query will give you coming Sunday in Y-m-d Format.

```
SELECT curdate() + Interval 6 - weekday(curdate()) DAY;
```

To get Monday, you can use

```
SELECT curdate() - Interval weekday(curdate()) DAY;
```

So basically you need to use these 2 dates and get all records between them. So your query will be

```
SELECT * 
FROM spec_roaster
WHERE DATE BETWEEN 
(curdate() - Interval weekday(curdate()) DAY) 
AND 
( SELECT curdate() + Interval 6 - weekday(curdate()) DAY )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The below code also worked for me

`SELECT * 
FROM spec_roaster
WHERE DATE(date)
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW())+ 7) % 7 DAY)
        AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW())+ 7) % 7 DAY)
ORDER BY date ASC`

to anyone who has been having a similar problem